# Filtering AJAX returned data and performing .each on selected elements within

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Lets say I have 4 tabs within nothing in them until they are clicked (lazy load concept).

When:

Tab1 is clicked: Data is inserted into that tab via ajax.

Tab2 is clicked: Data is inserted into that tab via ajax.

etc.

The data that's being returned consists of:

```
<ul class="elements">
  <li>
    <div>Stuff</div>
    <ul class="comments">
      ...Initially empty
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now in the success function I'm calling another function that gets all the comments associated with the li children of the parent ul.elements and this is where I'm having trouble.

So after all the elements are loaded into the tab, I have this function which needs doctoring:

```
function LoadComments(data) {
  $newData = $(data).filter('ul.elements');
  $newData.find('ul.comments').each(function() {
    var commentsHome = $(this);

$.ajax({
  url: '/MyFeed.aspx',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {
    "xfd" : "GetComments',
  },
  success: function(data) {
    commentsHome.html(data);
  }
});
  });
}
```

So far my variable `commentsHome` doesn't seem to be working. My goal here is to load the comments for each returned element of the new data only. So when Tab2 is clicked, this function is performed only on the data returned after clicking on Tab2.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: "GetComments' seems to be either a typo or your problem...

Comment: Actually it works in conjunction with the MyFeed.aspx so that isn't it.

Comment: You should really include ALL your HTML markup. So we can understand where the new elements are being placed, how they are classed and id'd.

Comment: You won't be able to access that control name via a variable (it won't be defined inside the success fn); but you can access it if you store the control name in a hidden input field, then read back the value inside your success function. Please see my response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commentsHome *variable* won't be available to you in the AJAX success function.

However, you can create a hidden `<input type="hidden" id="commentsHome" />` and store the value in there, then reference that in the AJAX success function.

```
function LoadComments(data) {
  $newData = $(data).filter('ul.elements');
  $newData.find('ul.comments').each(function() {
    $('#commentsHome').val($(this));


$.ajax({
  url: '/MyFeed.aspx',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {
    "xfd" : "GetComments',
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var commentsHome = $('#commentsHome).val();
    commentsHome.html(data);
  }
});
```